# Android Studio, need help understand App Permissions

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-5.0-lollipop

My App is set to Android 5.0. From my understanding, according to Google Developer documents under Permissions if app targets Android 6.0 then the permission have to be inside the app like custom permissions with iOS apps where the app developer creates a custom page for permissions?

While for app targets under 5.1.1 (like mine) when the user clicks on "install" in Google Play Store, permissions pop up and they have to accept all right away. (I don't own an Android so I don't know how it works).

Besides adding the "dangerous" permissions like Camera, Microphone, Location in my Android Manifest, do I still have to create a separate XML file with the same permissions where inside the app the user clicks on it and it takes them to Android Settings app or they just have to click "allow" or do I not even have to create this permissions XML anymore?

Comment: "I don't own an Android so I don't know how it works" -- that's a problem that you need to fix. Do not ship an app that you have not tested on hardware. "do I still have to create a separate XML file with the same permissions" -- what "separate XML file" are you referring to? You need `<uses-permission>` elements in the manifest, plus Java code to request `dangerous` permissions at runtime.

Comment: I'm coming from an iOS background. By Separate XML file, I mean like in iOS where inside the app when you're signing up to it for first time, eventually you get to a page with permissions. You have to click on "Camera" for example, an alertDialog pops up, you click on "Settings", it takes you to settings app and you have to click "allow" in settings app. That's what i'm referring to with "separate XML file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I still have to create a separate XML file with the same permissions where inside the app the user clicks on it and it takes them to Android Settings app or they just have to click "allow" or do I not even have to create this permissions XML anymore?

There never was this sort of XML file for Android, and there is none now.

For Android 6.0+ runtime permissions, you need to have all of the `<uses-permission>` elements that you had in your manifest from before. In addition, in Java code, you will request the permissions at runtime, using methods like `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` and `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`.

Comment: You mentioned 6.0. But my minSDKversion is 21, 5.0, lollipop. I already have the <uses-permission> implemented but I also have to use ContextCompat and ActivityCompat for 5.0 as well? Do I have to code additional information if the user doesn't allow the permission or does the app not install at all if they don't allow even 1 "dangerous" permission?

Comment: @iBEK: "I also have to use ContextCompat and ActivityCompat for 5.0 as well?" -- those classes are backwards-compatible. They will have no effect on older Android devices, behaving in a default fashion (e.g., `checkSelfPermission()` will say that you have the permission). "Do I have to code additional information if the user doesn't allow the permission" -- prior to Android 6.0, it is not possible for the user to not allow the permission. If your code is running, you have permission.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, I just wasn't too certain. Also, I'm not going to ship an app to Play Store without testing it on device.